# submatch(0) gives an empty string

Tags: vim

In vim script (gvim72) I use

```
substitute("abcdef", '.*' , submatch(0).'append','g')
```

which gives `'append'` instead of `'abcdefappend'`, What happens here?

Answer (score 3):

`submatch()` does not do what you intend inside `substitute()`, because the `submatch(0)` is evaluated and passed into the function, rather than being handled symbolically.

What you want is to evaluate it at replacement time:

```
substitute("abcdef", ".*", "\\=submatch(0).'append'", "g")
```

See help for `submatch()`, `substitute()` and (most of all) `sub-replace-expression`.

Comment: If you switch ' and ", then you do not have to double the backslash.  @withparadox:  are you going to accept the answer?

Comment: @withparadox2 Did you deliberately unaccept this answer?

Answer (score 1):

For something this simple you may as well use the backreference syntax instead of submatch:

```
substitute("abcdef", '.*' , '\0append','g')
```